# error: "was not declared in this scope", using cygwin

Tags: multithreading, cygwin, codeblocks, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to build a simple c++ code, that uses threads.
I tried to build it with Eclipse, Code Blocks, and Cygwin shell. All have resulted in the error:
"was not declared in this scope".

I added the -std=c++14 to the compiler options.

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 7.4.0
```

and here's what I get:

```
$>g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
     thread t1(callback, 1, 2);
     ^~~~~~
```

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: ...without seeing what code was in the compiled attempt, how do we know?

Comment: try removing `-std=c++14` or using `-std=g++14`

Comment: Are you missing a header? Or maybe a compiler option to enable threads? And btw, you are using an old version of the compiler. Run Cygwin setup to update the installation.

Comment: Have you wrote std::thread ?

Comment: Yes I have.
The same code compiles on Linux machine (IDE is eclipse), and also on Win machine (IDE is Visual Studio) but it doesn't compile on Win with eclipse. I guess the MinGW compiler doesn't support it (yet).